# HTML Valid method to implement this following

Tags: html, markup, w3c-validation

Running the Ubuntu cloud page http://www.ubuntu.com/business/cloud/overview through http://validator.w3.org/ gives several errors, the majority of which are centred around not having `<divs>` and `<h>`s etc. within an `<a>` tag.

The implementation I'm interested in is the four boxes with arrows, which change colour as you hover over them (as they are `<a>` links). What is the valid method to implement this?

Comment: The way to implement that would be CSS.  Why is it so important to you that the markup validates?

Comment: I can implement similar features myself, it was more whether there was a 'correct' way of doing it which validated. It doesn't really bother me either way if it validates or not, just was a point of interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid ways to implement this:

- separate links inside each block. Put the `:hover` effect on the parent div, not the link. Downside: more markup
- use only inline elements inside a single link, using CSS to change them into `display: block` elements if necessary. Downside: potentially less semantic
- use an HTML5 doctype, as [X]HTML5 allows this construction. Downside: the less easy-to-validate current moving-target nature of HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Each one of those can be a  (with a :hover effect to change the background color/image), and the , which sits inside, just covers the entire div with a `height` and a `width` in your CSS.